Choosing DDR3 for Zynq-7000 (XC7Z010-1CLG400I)
Looking at the AC characteristics of the Zynq-7000 it is said that the maximum data rate of the -1 speed grade is 800Mbit/s (it is also specifically mentioned that the clock frequency for data transfer is half which makes sense because of the dual rate). But when browsing the DDR3 memory ICs, the frequency of the DDR3 memories doesn't go as low as 400MHz. However, the available frequencies are conveniently aligned with the data rates (Mbit/s) of the Zynq-7000 -1 and other speed grades. As the information is contradicting, I would like to clarify - can I assume that the specified data rates refer to the frequency that is specified in the DDR3 memory IC specification?

DDR3 ICs are typically listed by their transfer rate, not their clock rate.  If you have an 800 Mbit/s/pin DRAM bus then you need DDR3-800.
